# Ensuring capacitor doesn't get above certain voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I have a circuit here (schematic below) that I've put together, based on US Patent US5439374. The idea is to sense the presence of a flame. I will be breadboarding the circuit before I make a PCB, but following a guide [here](https://www.pjrc.com/pilot-light-flame-sensor-for-burning-man-art/), it is noted that the capacitor can end up with a decently high voltage on it. Certainly one that would at least be too much for a microcontroller input, like an arduino. Thus, the author puts an op amp with a NPN transistor to manage the stored voltage in the capacitor.

To that end, I have tried my best here to implement that since the author doesn't give a full schematic. Truthfully, I'm new to using op amps/comparators, so I have no idea if this is the correct use. Would this circuit successfully regulate the capacitor to max of 5v? I added R5 to try to slow the drain on the capacitor to limit the current through the comparator to 20mA at 5v.

[image: Flame sensor circuit diagram]

Comment: An LM311 is a comparator (with an open-collector output), not an opamp.

Comment: @brhans Yes I am finding that there is a difference, of course after I posted. But thank you for the heads up

Comment: You can always just stick a TL431 programmed to the desired voltage across the capacitor.

Comment: ...or just use a Zener diode if there's one of a suitable voltage available

Comment: Use a capacitor rated for higher voltages (e.g. 100 VDC) because parallel zener diodes will add too much leakage current here. As I understand the circuit, R5 (250 ohm!) will discharge C2 all time and U1 has no chance to change the voltage at C2 significantly. Common mode input voltage range of U2 is violated with IN- at 5 V anyway.

Comment: @Jens wouldn't R5 only have an effect when the capacitor has charged enough for the comparator to open?

Comment: @EmanuelElliott Initially C2 is discharged, IN+ is below IN-, so comparator output is low and any charge coming via D1 is immediately flowing trough R5 into the low output. C2 will never charge, consider R5 parallel to C2.

Comment: @Jens Ah, so I have the comparator wired backwards then? As in, IN+ should be my 5v reference and IN- should be the capacitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The op-amp / comparator circuit is overkill for this.

To limit the voltage across the capacitor, the simplest and cheapest way is to use a zener diode. Find one with a rated voltage around the maximum voltage the capacitor should reach, and place it reverse-biased across the capacitor (i.e. cathode connected to the positive terminal of the capacitor).

However, be aware that the conduction curve of zener diodes is not particularly sharp - they will start to conduct significantly below their rated voltage, and only reach that voltage once a significant current is flowing. For example, a 5.1V zener may start to conduct at ~4V. Check that this is ok for your application.

If you need a sharp cutoff, then use a TL431 shunt regulator. It works exactly like a zener diode, except it has a sharp cutoff voltage that can be programmed with two resistors.

[image: TL431]

Bear in mind that the TL431 has a low current capability, less than 100mA, but looking at your schematic the resistor values seem high enough that you won't reach such currents.

Comment: Nice! Yeah that looks in line with the comments on the main post. I don't need a particularly hard switch, so I think I'll go with a regular zener. Thanks!